# How can I make this code work properly?

Tags: c#, php

So I've been learning how to make a C# application that sends and receive parameters with a LAMP server recently but I seem to have hit a wall and I need some help understanding what have I done wrong here.

This is a simple test application that sends two parameters (login and password) to a php file and receives the response according to the parameters being correct or not.

```
private void btEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String login, senha, postData, requestMethod = "POST", contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", responseFromServer = null;
        String urlLogin = "http://192.168.1.107/knowledgems/accounts/login.php";

        login = tbLogin.Text;
        senha = tbSenha.Text;
        postData = "param1=" + login + "&param2=" + senha;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlLogin);
        WebResponse response;
        Stream dataStream;
        StreamReader reader;

        //Send request
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //Get response
        response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        if (responseFromServer.Equals("SUCCESS"))
            MessageBox.Show("Login efetuado.");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Login não efetuado." + responseFromServer);
    } //btEntrar
```

Although everything seems correct and I can in fact get a response from my php file, I'm not able to go through the validation function at the end

```
(if (responseFromServer.Equals("SUCCESS")))
```

even though the response shown is exactly the string "SUCCESS" I seem to not be able to compare the responseFromServer string with "SUCCESS" to check if everything is ok to login, so it always ends up reading the else condition instead.

Following I'm also posting my php file.

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
header('Content-Type: application/form-data');

class User {
    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new DB_Connection();
        $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();            
    } //__construct

    public function does_user_exist($username,$password){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username' AND user_password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "SUCCESS";     
        } //if
        else {
            echo "ERRO&101";            
        } //else            
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    } //does_user_exist     

} //class

$user = new User();
if (isset($_POST['param1'],$_POST['param2'])){
    $username = $_POST['param1'];
    $password = $_POST['param2'];
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        //$encrypted_password = md5($password);
        $user -> does_user_exist($username,$password);
    }
    else {
        echo "ERRO&100";
    } //else
} //if
?>
```

Thanks for your time in advance, and please help!

Edit1: My guess is that the format is not quite right for the contentType, but I can't figure out what would be the right way to do it.

Comment: What if the response has a newline or something; does this work: `responseFromServer.Trim().Equals("SUCCESS")`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't believe something this simple solved my problems. Shame on me I guess, thanks for the immediate solution!

Comment: This why examine data (strings, whatever) in hexadecimal is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might "SUCCESS" have a newline on the end? See if this works:

```
if (responseFromServer.Trim().Equals("SUCCESS"))
{
```